# "the Size property has an invalid size of 0 addparam" error when I use StoredProcedureEFCore Nuget package

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I am using StoredProcedureEFCore nuget package for my .net core pwa project. 
I am trying to use stored procedure with some string output parameters but when I ran it, It gives error message "the Size property has an invalid size of 0"

I have read documentation but can not find something for string size : 
https://github.com/verdie-g/StoredProcedureEFCore

```
also I have tested this: 
I test this:
bookNameParameter.Size = 500;

but it does not work for this nuget package.
C#
context.LoadStoredProc("dbo.Book_Details")
                .AddParam("BookId", bookId)
                .AddParam("Id", out IOutParam<long> id)
                .AddParam("BookName", out IOutParam<string> bookNameParameter)
                .AddParam("ProducerName", out IOutParam<string> producerNameParameter)
                .AddParam("EnBookName", out IOutParam<string> enBookNameParameter)
                .AddParam("EnProducerName", out IOutParam<string> enProducerNameParameter)
                .AddParam("Content", out IOutParam<string> contentParameter)
                .AddParam("Type", out IOutParam<int> TypeParameter)
                .AddParam("Price", out IOutParam<int> PriceParameter)
                .AddParam("DiscountPrice", out IOutParam<int> DiscountPriceParameter)
                .AddParam("LikeCount", out IOutParam<int> likeCountParameter)
                .AddParam("BaseLikeCount", out IOutParam<int> baseLikeCountParameter)
                .AddParam("BookPage", out IOutParam<int> BookPageParameter)
                .AddParam("PublisherName", out IOutParam<string> publisherNameParameter)
                .AddParam("BookSize", out IOutParam<int> BookSizeParameter)
                .AddParam("LanguageType", out IOutParam<int> LanguageTypeParameter)
                .AddParam("PresentationMode", out IOutParam<int> PresentationModeParameter)
                .AddParam("ISBN", out IOutParam<string> ISBNParameter)
                .AddParam("BookVersion", out IOutParam<long> bookVersionParameter)
                .AddParam("AverageRate", out IOutParam<float> averageRateParameter)
                .Exec(r => lstEpisode = r.ToList<Episode>());
```

How can I define Size for these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the size of every `IOutParam<string>` like this

```
.AddParam("BookName", out IOutParam<string> bookNameParameter,500)
```